# how to have link router on. material ui list item, but not on one button in the list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

have a component that contains some ListItem components (from material ui), and each ListItem has a button. The whole listitem should be clickable and route the app somewhere, except for that button, which onclick should execute an action.
But right now, when I click the delete button, it will route the app to that path. I want to be able to delete the item (my delete method in the parent will actually open a dialog to confirm that, but I guess that is irrelevant). I just want it to ignore the route when clicking the icon.
How do I handle this case?
Here's the code:

```
<ListItem
  component={Link}
  to={`item/${props.id}`}
  alignItems="flex-start"
>
  <ListItemAvatar>
    <Avatar />
  </ListItemAvatar>
  <ListItemText
    disableTypography={false}
    primary={props.b}
    secondary={props.c}
    className={classes.body}
  />
  <IconButton
    onClick={props.deleteItem}
    aria-label="delete"
    className={classes.button}
  >
    <DeleteIcon />
  </IconButton>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deleteItem function should get event as an argument. And call event.stopPropagation();

Updated:

event.preventDefault();

Comment: yeah, but i want to be able to delete the item. and when i click the delete the icon, it does both routing and "deleting". but deleting will open a dialog to confirm delete. And that doesn't happen because it will be routed to the actual item.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation is it your case?

Comment: ah, i think i see it now. let me try that. thank you

Comment: event.preventDefault(); is the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this:

1. Put the icon button outside the wrapper and position it on top of the link using position relative top bottom etc.
2. Use `event.stopPropogation` and sometimes `event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`
3. Stop propagation didn't work for me once so what I did was added id's to the divs then onclick check if the id is the one you want the action to be executed on, if yes proceed with the action. You can use react-routers `history.push()` syntax to do it programmatically and if the id is of the button do that action. This way you'll only need on onClick on the wrapper and not on the button itself. I know this is a bit hacky but worked out for me once.